# Toggle boolean in hashmap

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

The following works but feels/seems wrong. Is there a better way?

```
dev:cljs.user=> (def x (atom {:v true}))
#'cljs.user/x
dev:cljs.user=> (swap! x assoc-in [:v] (not (:v @x)))
{:v false}
dev:cljs.user=> (swap! x assoc-in [:v] (not (:v @x)))
{:v true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let [a (atom {:v true})]
    (swap! a update-in [:v] not)
    @a)
=> {:v false}
```

or you can use specter:

```
(transform [ATOM :v] not a)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cljs.user=> (def x (atom {:v true}))
#'cljs.user/x
cljs.user=> (swap! x update :v not)
{:v false}
cljs.user=> @x
{:v false}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22583337)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, while brevity is acceptable, please try to add a fuller explanation of why this solution is a better one.